# SQL - consulta en la cláusula WHERE para relacionar tablas

Tags: sql, pgadmin

soy totalmente nuevo con SQL y quería consultar si estoy haciendo la consulta de forma correcta.

Las tablas que tengo son las que muestro a continuación:

| tb_invoice | tb_customer | tb_site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code – foreign key company | Cust_no – primary key | Cust_no |
| Invoice_id – primary key | Name | Id – primary key |
| Invoice_no | Cif | Code |
| Cust_no - foreign key customer | Last_updated_by | Name |
| Site_id- foreign key site | Last_update_date | Address |
| Payednet_amount |  | City |
| Iva_amount |  | Country |
| Tot_amount |  | Phone |
| Last_updated_by |  |  |
| Last_update_date |  |  |

Lo que quiero es localizar las facturas de clientes con dirección en Granada y ordenar de forma ascendiente por número de cliente y descendiente por número de factura.

El código que he planteado es el siguiente:

```
FROM erp.tb_invoice AS i, erp.tb_customer AS c, erp.tb_site AS s
WHERE i.cust_no = s.cust_no
    AND c.cust_no = s.cust_no
    AND s.site_city = 'Granada'
ORDER BY i.cust_no, i.invoice_no DESC;
```

La duda que me queda es en la cláusula `WHERE`
Los resultados no son iguales según lo que añada en `AND c.cust_no = s.cust_no`.
Si lo elimino, el resultado es diferente y estoy seguro que debo usarlo pero no entiendo por qué cambia en caso de no indicarlo.

Estoy haciéndolo bien tal y como lo planteo?

Gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al eliminar una condición, estás eliminando la relación entre dos tablas y generando que se relacionen todas las filas de una tabla con todas las filas de la otra tabla. Por este tipo de confusiones, es por lo que siempre recomiendo dejar de utilizar la sintaxis antigua y en vez de eso utilizar `JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM erp.tb_invoice  AS i
JOIN erp.tb_site     AS s ON i.cust_no = s.cust_no
JOIN erp.tb_customer AS c ON c.cust_no = s.cust_no
WHERE s.site_city = 'Granada'
ORDER BY i.cust_no, 
         i.invoice_no DESC;
```

Así podemos dejar más claro cuales son condiciones para unir tablas y cuales son condiciones para limitar resultados.